# Integrating QR code API with c++

Tags: c++, api, integration, qr-code

Is it possible to integrate a QR-code API in a C++ console application (http://goqr.me/api/) and auto save the pictures in a folder?

The format of the QR API is

> https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=###########

API Documentation: http://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/

where `#######` is the number or sentence I want to generate a QR code of.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, if you want to do just requests against that web API? In that case, just use a library like `libcurl` to do web requests and handle the response in your program.

Comment: i want to make a request and download the barcode to a specific folder

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the information given: Yes it is.

Take a look at `libcurl` (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/), although it's a `C` library there are several `C++` bindings you can use, for instance:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/

There are basic examples on the `curl` webpage for making requests and handling response (I assume you now how to save data from memory to file in C++). This should be all you need.